# I mixed Miracle Gro fertilizer and Soil Mender Liquid Fish in my hose-end sprayer to save time. The mixture became very cold. Why?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Miracle Gro = Ammonium Sulfate, Potassium Phosphate, Potassium Chloride, Urea, Urea Phosphate, Boric Acid, Copper Sulfate, Iron EDTA, Manganese EDTA, Sodium Molybdate, Zinc Sulfate.

Soil Mender Liquid Fish = hydrolyzed fish.

Why would mixing these together in the jug of my hose-end sprayer cause the mixture to become very cold? Nothing else added.

Comment: Endothermic dissolution.